# What words in the English language are derived from the latin word "gustus"?

Tags: etymology, english, spanish

Are there words in the English language that are derived from the Latin word ***gustus***?

I am wondering if there are cognates in the English language so that the Spanish phrase "mucho gusto" could possibly be translated to something other than "it is good to meet you."

Comment: An English word can be derived from Latin (through some loan) or it can be cognate with a Latin word (i.e. both inherited from a common ancestor in Proto-Indo-European), but not both. There actually probably is a true cognate: [*cost*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cost#Etymology_3) 'manner, way' (not the normal *cost*). Incidentally, note that English *much* and Spanish *mucho* are not related; *mucho* is from Latin *multus*, which doesn't have cognates in Germanic.

Answer (score 9):

I can't comment on the Spanish, but I can on the Latin. In fact, the word [*gusto*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gusto) is an English word, and comes, via Italian, from the Latin *gustus*.

From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gusto):

> a. an individual or special taste
> b. enthusiastic and vigorous enjoyment or appreciation
> c. vitality marked by an abundance of vigor and enthusiasm

I usually see it in meanings b and c.

There are additional words that come from the same Latin root (like gustatory and disgust), but they come from the verb *gustare* instead.

Comment: The word also exists in an obsolete form [without the -o](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gust), a homonym to the burst of wind which has different roots.